# What is the Syntax to get weekly data in addition to monthly data from a query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have written a query that gives me the numbers I need for a month over month comparison for custom orders. I'd like to get weekly data as well. What is the syntax that could give me both?

I've written an entire query that works very well for the monthly report but I've been asked to dive deeper into the data to get the weekly numbers as well.

```
 SELECT t.customerref_name, t.customerref_value, t.txndate AS full_date, 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(t.txndate AS DATE)) AS month, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM 
t.txndate) AS year,
r.description, r.amount, r.estimate_id, r.qty, 
s.first_invoice_order_date, 
s.last_invoice_order_date, DATE_DIFF(s.last_invoice_order_date,  
s.first_invoice_order_date, DAY) AS days_been_csutomer,
NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(s.last_invoice_order_date, 
s.first_invoice_order_date, DAY)) AS percentile_lifetime, r.color,
```

Is it possible? This is just a snippet of my code but I can share the rest if need be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day) month` you can use `EXTRACT(WEEK FROM day) week`

So, if your monthly query can be mimicked as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT day, CAST(100 * RAND() AS INT64) value
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2000-01-01', '2001-12-31')) day
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day) year, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day) month, SUM(value) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month
```

Then, your weekly will be

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT day, CAST(100 * RAND() AS INT64) value
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2000-01-01', '2001-12-31')) day
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day) year, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM day) week, SUM(value) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY year, week
ORDER BY year, week
```

You can learn more about syntax of [EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, I'll test it.

Comment: @Trail_Bear - glad it helped  - consider voting up :o)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mikhail's answer, consider using `FORMAT_DATE('%U', day) as week_num`.  This approach provides a few different format elements to give you more flexibility: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-datetime .

`%U`    The week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number (00-53).

`%V`    The week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number (01-53). If the week containing January 1 has four or more days in the new year, then it is week 1; otherwise it is week 53 of the previous year, and the next week is week 1.

`%W`    The week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number (00-53).